# How to implement wavesurfer-js in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, wavesurfer.js

I am using wavesurfer-js angular 6  application,the player opens with no controls and also with an error says :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wavesurfer' of undefined

Here is my ts code :

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatBottomSheetRef } from '@angular/material';
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
import VideojsWavesurfer from 'videojs-wavesurfer';
import SpectrogramPlugin from 
'wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.spectrogram.min.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio-page',
  templateUrl: './audio-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio-page.component.scss'],
})
export class AudioPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public wavesurfer: WaveSurfer;
  constructor(private bottomSheetRef: 
MatBottomSheetRef<AudioPageComponent>){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    let audiofile = 
 "https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox
/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3"
    this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform',
  height:100,
  waveColor : 'red',
  scrollParent: true,
  progressColor: 'purple',
  plugins: [
      SpectrogramPlugin.create({
          container: "#wave-spectrogram"
      })
  ]
});

this.wavesurfer.load(audiofile);        

  this.wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
      this.wavesurfer.play();
  });

 }

}
```

and my HTML :

```
  <div id="waveform"></div>
  <div id="wave-spectrogram"></div>
```

Comment: did you include `wavesurfer`, `videojs-wavesurfe` and `wavesurfer.spectrogram` to your **angular.json**?

Comment: no, how to add it, i mean the syntax

Comment: please include your **angular.json** in the question

Comment: Change the way you do import --> import * as WaveSurfer...

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Include the wavesurfer.js in your Angular project's index.html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
```

**Step 2**
In the component you wish to use WaveSufer, right after your imports, add:

```
declare var WaveSurfer;
```

**Step 3**
Declare a variable in your class

```
protected waveSurfer = null;
```

**Step 4**
Create an instance:

```
this.waveSurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
   container:'#my-wave-div'
});
```